# How to configure Spring new release with Hibernate and Struts

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, struts2

I am reading a tutorial for Struts2 Spring Hibernate. at here
www.springsource.org/download/community
 While coming towards Spring I found link to download spring framework which I don't find on Spring Website I saw couple of existing answers but still confused how 21 mb files are just replaced by 5 or 6 lines of code as it suggests to write these dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Please tell me because I am in the half of the tutorial and almost spent a day and now cannot move to another tutorial. What should I configure in my project with new release of Spring ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a maven dependency. Maven is a system for managing dependencies. You can find more information on the [maven homepage](http://maven.apache.org)